# Binding SharePoint list data to Kendo grid after button click

Tags: sharepoint, kendo-grid, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

I have a search page, where user enter fields and click on search button. Then I am making ajax call to Sharepoint 2013 list with search query and fetching data. After fetching data I am binding data to Kendo grid.

This SharePoint list contains different type of fields like: look up, choice, text field. Data from choice column, text field types are getting bind to grid easily, I am able to see the data too. But data from look up columns is not being seen in Kendo Grid.

Instead of data, its showing

> [object Object]

Below is the code of ajax call I am making and in success I am binding data to Kendo Grid.

```
function fetchData(webUrl, filterString){
    $.ajax({
        url: webUrl +"/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Inventory')/Items?$filter="+filterString,
        method: 'get',
        contentType: 'application/json;odata=verbose',
        headers:{
            'X-RequestDigest': $('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val(),
            'Accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose'
        },
        success: function(data){
            var grid = $('#grdInventory').getKendoGrid();
            grid.dataSource.data(data.d.results);
            grid.refresh();
        }
    });
}
```

- Below is the screenshot of the Grid: In Grid=

ID, short description, Analytic ID, Analytic Name are text type column

Production status is choice column,

State, Platform are look up column in SharePoint

[image: I circled the errors which is being seen]

- Below is the screenshot of data being seen in Browser Console:

[image: Circled lookup Columns]

Can anyone please help me or give me hint of how to display look up column data in Kendo Grid.

Answer (score 0):

That's a standard behavior, Lookup field values in that case represent a complex property and returned as object. Depending on what field from lookup list should be displayed (lets assume `Title` in our example), you could apply the following filter for returned data before the grid is getting displayed:

```
 var items = data.d.results.map(function(item){
     item.State = item.State.Title; //lets get Title from Lookup object  
     return item;
 });
```

and then bind the data:

```
var grid = $('#grdInventory').getKendoGrid();
grid.dataSource.data(items);
grid.refresh();
```